# Remove duplicates maps equal to condition Groovy / Grails

Tags: groovy

I would like to remove duplicates maps equal to some conditions, I have the maps below:

```
    def map = [[name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"aaaa", title:null],[name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"aaaa",title:"something"],[name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"bbbb",title:"something"]]
```

I tried with the code below to do that, but its not working

```
 def newMap = map.unique {a, b -> (a.name == b.name && a.invoice == b.invoice && a.bilD == b.bilD)}
```

How can I get a map like below

```
 [
        [name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"aaaa",title:"somethingOrNull"],[name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"bbbb",title:"something"]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection.unique(Closure)` behaves differently depending on the number of parameters in the closure. When the closure has one parameter it expects...

> ...a value used for comparison (either using
>   Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object) or
>   Object#equals(java.lang.Object)).

However, if the closure contains two arguments, as shown in your example, then the closure must return an integer...

```
...with 0 indicating the items are not unique
```

Strangely, the two-argument closure behavior seems to be in exact opposite of how it's described. Here's a working example:

```
def maps = [
    [name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"aaaa"],
    [name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"aaaa"],
    [name: "111F", invoice:"40",bilD:"bbbb"]
]

assert maps.unique(false) {a, b -> 
    a.name == b.name && a.invoice == b.invoice && a.bilD == b.bilD ? 0 : 1
} == [['name':'111F', 'invoice':'40', 'bilD':'aaaa'], ['name':'111F', 'invoice':'40', 'bilD':'bbbb']]
```

However, in your case, you can simply use unique() without the closure:

```
assert maps.unique(false) == [['name':'111F', 'invoice':'40', 'bilD':'aaaa'], ['name':'111F', 'invoice':'40', 'bilD':'bbbb']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is, add all the elements to a set, then transform the resulting set back to list (note, that your variable `map` actually contains a list).

The shortest way I can think of would be calling:

```
def newMap = (map as Set) as List
```

Comment: Your code works indeed with my first map example, but I made a mistake sorry for that, there is other element in my map named (title), sometime filled and sometime empty, I edited my question, when I try your code it returns 3 maps instead of 2. any idea how to fix this?